# mysql - update,delete,alter,rename,create,repair = gone away

Tags: mysql

I am getting a weird error and hadn't find any answer.

I have a little table (~200 id) who worked fine, but today everytime i want to do update,delete,alter,rename,create or even repair the request take many time and finish with "server gone away".

I export the table then duplicate it on the same server and everything work just fine. But can't do anything with the first one exept display it rows.

Anyone already face that ?

Server :  5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.2
MySQL: 5.5.29[enter image description here][1]
MyISAM
structure: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuXe3.png

thanks for helping.

Comment: Got SSH access? Maybe try via client on the server... it could give you some more feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i understood what's going on ... My server was under attack and a $_GET wasn't protected. Then someone inject a "sleep" in the query. So the table couldn't respond back.

IP of the hacker : 62.102.148.158 probably with acunetix.

Thanks for you're time !

Answer (score 0):

the database or table is probably corrupt and the server gets a error and hangs or disconnects the client. 
( thats why u get "gone away" the server timed out or disconected your client )

becouse u say u created a copy table that works i think easest is to do the folowing from the mysql manual : 
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/rebuilding-tables.html

```
mysqldump db_name > dump.sql
mysql db_name < dump.sql
```

or try a :

```
mysqlcheck --repair --all-databases
```

And if that does not work try this manual : 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/gone-away.html